# Rsu same fro primary key and non-primary key - cosmos

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I have a cosmos db container and currently it has just 100 documents. So when I query with Indexed id (primary key) or non-primary key, then the rsu remains the same.

So, as I have more data, the rsu's will change right ? Or does cosmos calculates based on more data and gives an average ?

I have id (primary key) as some unique ids and I am setting partition keys to be same as id. Because few times, i need to query based on id. But now there is a new requirement to query also on the basis of non-primary key. So, should I add that to be a partition key (again - unique ids) or add a secondary index ?

The data is not yet in production.

Comment: Please edit to include some sample data, as well as the type of query / read you're doing. Right now, we can only guess at what you're doing. Not sure what you mean by non-primary key; unless you explicitly excluded a property from being indexed, queries against any property should yield the same RU cost (assuming same data type, same query). The only difference is if you're doing a point-read (not a query) against a specific ID+partitionkey value. Also FYI the cost of a query is a Request Unit, or `RU`. I suspect that's what you meant by `rsu`.

Answer (score 0):

At small sizes the choices you are making here likely won't have any impact either way on RU/s costs. It's only when you want to scale your workload that design decisions you make will have an impact.

If you are new to Cosmos DB, I would recommend you watch this presentation on how to model and partition data in Cosmos DB. https://youtu.be/utdxvAhIlcY